# Why is there a memory error showing when I try to run this code?

Tags: python, error-messaging

So I'm having to write a function that does this:
Write the function called remove_all_from_string that takes two strings and returns a copy of
the first string with all instances of the second string removed. You can assume that the
second string is only one letter, like "a". For example `remove_all_from_string("house", "h")`
would output "ouse" or `remove_all_from_string("haus", "h")` would output "aus".

It has to have:
A function definition with parameters.
A while loop.
The find method.
Slicing and the + operator.
A return statement.

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x = word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            continue
        else:
            new = list(word)
            new[x] = ""
            word = str(word[:x]) + word.join(new)
    return word

print(remove_all_from_string("Mississippi", "i"))
```

Every time I try to run this, Python displays an Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratchpad.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(remove_all_from_string("Mississippi", "i"))
  File "scratchpad.py", line 19, in remove_all_from_string
    word = str(word[:x]) + word.join(new)
MemoryError
```

Could anyone help with this? Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Please spell-out what exactly the following line is doing (step-by-step): `word = str(word[:x]) + word.join(new)`.

Comment: Are you forbidden to use `str` methods? Because otherwise, the correct solution here is just `return word.replace(letter, "")`, and what you're doing, even corrected, is wasteful. If you're forbidden to use the sane solution, please explain what limitations apply (clearly you can use conversions to `list`, and `str.find`/`str.join` is allowed, which makes it seem like `str.replace` should be fine too).

Answer (score 0):

Your code getting trapped in a forever loop because of `word.join(new)` that you are adding `word` again and again ant word grows to infinity.

The way you can fix your code:

```py
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x = word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            continue
        else:
            new = list(word)
            new[x] = ""
            word = "".join(new[:x] + new[x+1:])
    return word

print(remove_all_from_string("Mississippi", "i"))
```

Better way to implement this function:

```py
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    return word.replace(letter, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accumulating copies of the variable "word" into itself, which results in exponential growth of the data in the variable, resulting in the computer running out of RAM. Given the task description this is a bug.

As it seems you may be new to programming, I suggest this strategy for helping yourself: print the values of all your variables (and add new variables for important intermediate results) so you can see what your program is actually doing. Once you understand what the program is doing, you can begin to fix it.

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    debug_loop_count = 0
    while letter in word:
        debug_loop_count += 1
        if debug_loop_count > 2: # (change this to number control the # of loops you print)
            print(f"breaking loop because debug_loop_count exceeded")
            break
        print(f"--- begin loop iteration #{debug_loop_count}, word: '{word}'")
        x = word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            print(f"--- end loop iteration #{debug_loop_count} x={x} (continue)")
            continue
        else:
            new = list(word)
            print(f"variable new is: '{new}' x={x}")
            new[x] = ""
            print(f"variable new is updated to: '{new}' x={x}")
            str1 = str(word[:x])
            str2 = word.join(new)
            print(f"variable str1 is: '{str1}'")
            print(f"variable str2 is: '{str2}'")
            word = str1 + str2
            print(f"variable word now contains: '{word}'")
            print(f"--- end iteration loop #{debug_loop_count}")
    print(f"!!! end of function, word = {word}")
    return word


print(remove_all_from_string("Mississippi", "i"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simplify the while loop's logic:

There's already an answer with the 'best' way to solve the problem. In general, if I think I need a while loop I'm normally wrong, but if they're a requirement they're a requirement I guess.

```py
def remove_all_from_string_converted(word: str, letter: str) -> str:
    while letter in word:
        index: int = word.find(letter)
        word = word[:index] + word[index+1:]  # 'join' isn't necessary unless it's also required by a rule
    return word

print(remove_all_from_string_converted("Mississippi", "i"))
```

Output: `Msssspp`

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I was just overthinking it I suppose, which isn't something new.